# How do I highlight specific words as they are written, with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a script whereas words written in my textarea beginning with a "#" is to be highlighted in realtime, as they are written.
ex: The cutest **#animals** ever.

Any help with this problem is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't highlight things in a textarea. So your question is probably moot.

You could I suppose recreate an input box using a div and capturing keystrokes but it would be a huge amount of work.

Or you could do like this site does: Type in the textarea, and show the result under it.